# Inserting a row and manipulating values for the row

Tags: vba, excel

I am inserting a new row dynamically to my sheet With Row.Insert. I'd like to add some values in column B to that row I just added as in cell(my_new_row, 2).Value = myvalue. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the section of code where you insert the row. You are problably inserting a row before row "r". Your new row is now r. Then you can just do `cells(r,2).value = myvalue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do what you need ?

```
Sub AddRowToto()
    ' Optionnaly define here which row to select
    ActiveSheet.Rows("12:12").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Cells(1, 2) = "toto"
End Sub
```